# How to know post time of pic in instragram?

Tags: c#, json, interface, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get the post time of picture instagram by C#.
For example i got the next string from the server (JSON):
  `{"created_time":"1447156299","text":".........}`
what is the time?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows :

```
static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp){
DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```

You'll have to pass `"1447156299"` to double and then you'll be able to do it.

For more information check this [tutorial](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx)

### EDIT

```
// This is an example of a UNIX timestamp for the date/time 11-04-2005 09:25.
double timestamp = 1113211532;

// First make a System.DateTime equivalent to the UNIX Epoch.
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Add the number of seconds in UNIX timestamp to be converted.
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);

// The dateTime now contains the right date/time so to format the string,
// use the standard formatting methods of the DateTime object.
string printDate = dateTime.ToShortDateString() +" "+ dateTime.ToShortTimeString();

// Print the date and time
System.Console.WriteLine(printDate);
```

Taken from [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10081/UNIX-timestamp-to-System-DateTime)

Output with *1113211532* `UNIX timestamp`

> 4/11/2005 9:25 AM

Output with *1447156299* `UNIX timestamp`

> 11/10/2015 11:51 AM

Comment: I am getting current date. i think this is wrong.

Comment: where can i insert function FromUnixTimeSeconds?

Comment: still getting the current date

Comment: This is my output : `11/10/2015 11:51 AM`

Comment: Tried again? My output it's not the current date...

Comment: Shall I update my answer or so? or worked for you?